# Why is this UIView not presenting in front of a UITableView?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiview, addsubview

I have a UINavigationController/UITableView and I want to present a UIView over top of it when the table is empty to give the user a prompt on how to add items to the table.

I've never make a UIView (as opposed to a UIViewController before) so I'll step through what I did to make it:

1. Make a new UIView Class - MakeSentenceHelperView
2. Make a nib called MakeSentenceHelperView.xib
3. Set File's owner to MakeSentenceHelperView

Load the nib in the MakeSentenceHelperView:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        NSLog(@"makesentencehelperview init");
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MakeSentenceHelperView" owner:self options:nil];
    }
    return self;
}
```

and present the `MakeSentenceHelperView` in the UITableViewController:

```
        //present the placeholder view for sentences
        MakeSentenceHelperView *makeSentenceHelperView = [[MakeSentenceHelperView alloc] init];

        NSLog(@"present placeholder: self.navigationcontroller.view: %@", self.navigationController.view);

        //Something like this:
        [self.navigationController.view addSubview:makeSentenceHelperView];
        [self.navigationController.view bringSubviewToFront:makeSentenceHelperView];
```

The class loads and logs ok, but nothing appears in front of the UITableView - where have I gone wrong?

UPDATE: if I add `[self.tableView setHidden:YES];` then the tableview disappears and the space is black and empty. I'm assuming this means I'm setting up the View wrong, somewhere.

Comment: On subclassing a UIView with a nib, go through [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5056219/uiview-and-initwithframe-and-a-nib-file-how-can-i-get-the-nib-file-loaded)

Comment: That's a really helpful link, thank you- I implemented awakeFromNib and the other things they spoke of, but I'm still having the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Aadhira for their link which led me to the problem.

1. I needed to add awakeFromNib
2. I was missing [self addSubview:self.view]; at the end of initWithFrame.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/ecstasy2/toast-notifications-ios/ for showing Toast view liek Android. Check array size and if table view is not showing then called this one and show any custom method.

Comment: I don't really know what you mean. I just want to use a standard UIView.