# How do you associate a NIB file with a custom NSView class?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa-touch

I have a custom `myCustomNSView` class. I have also created a nib file for it.  How do i link the two together so that i can instantiate the myCustomNSView class and add it as a subview of some other view?  The answer provided by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5056219/uiview-and-initwithframe-and-a-nib-file-how-can-i-get-the-nib-file-loaded/5056886#5056886) is perfect except, I am working with OSX not iOS.

Looking at [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSBundle_AppKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000401-CJBGDIFB) i see the following:

[image]

How can this be done for OSX?

Answer (score 0):

If you look into the header `NSNib.h`, you will see that the new official method is:

```
- (BOOL)instantiateWithOwner:(id)owner topLevelObjects:(NSArray **)topLevelObjects
```

It is the Very same as for UIKit. I have no idea, why it is so poorly documented.