# Custom 'XiB' Based UI Control

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to implement a custom view ( C# Custom UserControl equivalent )

Use-case:

1. I have implemented a custom UIView based control
2. The Control is associated with a specialized XiB file ( **Xib file A** )
3. The 'File's Owner' of the XiB is a specialized class where IBOutlets are defined
4. This control is referred to by a different XiB file ( **XiB file B** )

I was expecting **Xib file A** elements to be rendered within **Xib file B**, however, The UI wasn't presented although all IBOutlets were properly associated, and 'awakeFromNib' was called.

What am I doing wrong here ?

The following is the code for the cusom XiB based ~control~ ( which is referred to by another control/view of a different XiB)

```
@interface SeriesView ()
@property (strong, atomic, readonly) MediaViewer* mediaViewer;
- (void) OnInitialize;
- (void) awakeFromNib;
@end

@implementation SeriesView

@synthesize mediaViewer = _mediaViewer;
@synthesize image = _image;
@synthesize scroll = _scroll;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    if(nil == (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]))
        return nil;
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SeriesView" owner:self options:nil];
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)aDecoder
{
    if(nil == (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]))
        return nil;
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SeriesView" owner:self options:nil];
    return self;
}

- (void) OnInitialize
{
    _mediaViewer = [[MediaViewer alloc] init];
    _image.hidden= NO;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
    [self OnInitialize];    
}
@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per: [UIView and initWithFrame and a NIB file. How can i get the NIB file loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5056219/uiview-and-initwithframe-and-a-nib-file-how-can-i-get-the-nib-file-loaded) 

The only part missing was

1. adding a view outlet to my custom view
2. Associating the view with the corresponding root view @ the XiB
3. calling '[self addSubview:self.view]' through awakeFromNib