# Objective C: Own controls for a blog

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, custom-controls

i want to make an app for a little blog. (Looks little bit like the facebook timeline)

There is already a website for it. I know that i can make a HTML document to an app, but i want a native version.The website looks like that:

[image: Image 1]

The scructure is very simple: Title, image, title.

Now: I solve it like that:

I have in my mainview a UIScrollView. And add the control:

[image: Image 2]

And add the controls in a foreach where i grab the data:

```
MangoListItem *myLabel = [[MangoListItem alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 40)];
[myLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[scrollView addSubview:myLabel]
```

First: Is this a good solution?

Second: How can i associate the .xib File with the .h File?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSString * nibName = @"MyCustomView";
[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:nibName owner:self options:nil] firstObject];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Where do i have to put that code?

Comment: put that in the viewdidload.  You could also simply instantiate your UIViewController using initWithNibName: from the start, that will save you some time, and be easier for you.  Take a look here for a tutorial: http://www.idev101.com/learn/view_controllers.html

Comment: Thank you for your help. I try to solve it in combination with this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14144672/custom-xib-based-ui-control