# Table view, manual and settings in one screen: Best practice?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am writing a text editing app. I target iOS 6 and 7, and use storyboards and autolayout.

I thought this layout for the welcome screen would work well:

```
<Files in a table view>
<Instructions to user>
<Settings>
```

The settings view is pretty complex, and will probably benefit from having its own view controller. The instructions view is static, and has no logic.

I can think of three ways to organize this:

1. Create this as a table with three sections, where the 1st section is the list of files, and the 2nd and 3rd section are big, custom cells with.
2. Wrap all three views in a scrollview
3. Wrap the instructions and settings in a scrollview

I prefer the first solution, as it seems to be the, most natural way for the user to navigate, but I haven't seen any examples of adding a viewcontroller as a cell for a tableview anywhere, and haven't been able to google me any. Prototype cells do not seem like the right way to go for the settings view/controller either.

Best practice, suggestions, input?

Comment: Don't you think that the UI experience here would be a little weird. For example, if I use your app often I will probably never care about instructions after the first time I use it, why make the user move through the Instructions to get to the Settings. What if I have hundreds of files? It will get annoying to scroll through them all to also get to Settings. Why not just use a tab bar controller or some other UI feature that is designed for something like this?

Comment: The user will usually not have hundreds of files. The instructions are very simple and short. The settings are very rarely used. The point would be to flatten the hierarchy - most users really struggle with the tab bar abstraction.

Comment: "most users really struggle with the tab bar abstraction" -- why do you think this is true? It seems to me a tab bar setup would be the most natural for this set of views.

Comment: No offense, but I am really not interested in comment on the design - only in comments on ways to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple recommends only one view controller per "screen," so that rules out option 1.   I wouldn't want to even start to attempt to embed a viewcontroller in a table cell and that just smells very wrong in any case.

You have three independent views that you want to scroll, and that clearly calls for a UIScrollView.  As for the best way to organize this, I recommend creating modular UIView subclasses: one for the table, one for the instructions, one for the settings.   See my answer on this question as to how you can package up views as reusable (not important in your case) and modular widgets: [UIView and initWithFrame and a NIB file. How can i get the NIB file loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5056219/uiview-and-initwithframe-and-a-nib-file-how-can-i-get-the-nib-file-loaded/5056886#5056886).   Then you can create delegate interfaces for each one, and set your main view controller to implement them in order to communicate with each of the three "widgets."