# UITableView delegate methods not called from UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using a `UIView` as a popup in my app.

I have added a `UITableview`in to this `UIVIew`. However, the content of the `UITableView` doesn't get populated. I have set the `delegate` and `datasource` from `IB` and also from the code as well.

None of the`Delegate` methods are being called.

Code as follows:

```
-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{

    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

self.tablev.delegate = self;

        self. tablev.dataSource = self;


        [self addSubview:self. tablev];

}
```

View `.h` class

```
@interface MyView : UIView <UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
```

UPDATE

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    MyView

 *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"c" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil)

    {

        cell = [[MyView

 alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle

                                             reuseIdentifier:@"c"];

    }

    cell.la.text=@"hiiiii";
```

Comment: r u created the table in progrmatically have u allocated the frame and memory of tableview

Comment: no i have created it via interface builder.

Comment: r u used storyboard or xib, if you are created it via interface builder remove that line **[self addSubview:self. tablev];**

Comment: is your tableView outlet connected ?

Comment: @DheerajSingh Yes, i dragged the component and dropped it on the .h file.

Answer (score 0):

1) If you have created the UIView popup and Table View using Interface Builder, then just set the delegate and dataSource of the table view in xib and also in this case you need not to add the tableview to the view (like `[self addSubview:tableView]`), because it's already added via on he view while creating it in xib.

2) If you need to set any thing via code on the views which are created using xib than use

`- (void) awakeFromNib { }`  method of the corresponding view

`awakeFromNib` is called after the xib is loaded and it's subviews could be populated/customized.

3) Implement the delegate and dataSource methods

Comment: Take a look at my `cellForRowAtIndexPath `  this method never gets called

Comment: I am still having this issue, Help.

Answer (score 0):

I think -

1) Your view should be MyView created using xib

2) Add a table view on this view (in xib), and set delegate and data source

3) Crete a class for CustomCell (using which cells will be created)

4) Implement the delegate and dataSource methods in MyView class

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"c" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"c"];
    }

    cell.la.text=@"hiiiii";

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: That was exactly what i did.

Comment: you may not have initialized you xib file correctly in  your view...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5056219/uiview-and-initwithframe-and-a-nib-file-how-can-i-get-the-nib-file-loaded

Comment: above in your code you have added the delegates and datasource on MyView as -  @interface MyView : UIView <UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate> and you are creating a instance of MyView

Comment: basically you are adding the table view on a view and creating the cell from  same view, this is confusing?

Answer (score 0):

I was doing something similar and faced the same problem. `UITableViewDataSource` methods were not being called in my case. In my case this happened because the array used for populating the table was `weak`, I made it `strong` and problem was solved for me. Hope this will also help you.