# Subclassing custom UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uicollectionview

I've succesfully created custom UICollectionViewCell that has 3 labels.

Now I want to subclass it, add dateToDisplay property and in setDateToDisplay change labels's strings (with custom date formatters).

**Creation and usage of parentCell:**

```
ParentCellIdentifier.h    
static NSString *ParentCellIdentifier = @"ParentCellIdentifier";

@interface ParentCell : UICollectionViewCell
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *firstLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *secondLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *thirdLabel;

-(void)setupDefaults;
@end
```

**In parentCell.xib:**

Class set to `ParentCell` and Identifier set to `ParentCellIdentifier`

**In ViewController I have `UICollectionView`:**

```
-(void)setupCollectionView {
     [_daysCollectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"ParentCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:ParentCellIdentifier];
    _daysCollectionView.delegate = self;
    _daysCollectionView.dataSource = self;
    _daysCollectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
ParentCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:ParentCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.firstLabel.text = @"first";
    cell.secondLabel.text = @"second";
}
```

**The setup above worked like a charm.
No I want to add ChildCell, using same xib as previously:**

```
@interface ChildCell : ParentCell
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate* dateToDislpay;//labels of parentCell updated using dateformatters on setDateToDisplay:
@end
```

`-(void)setupCollectionView` left the same, registering ParentCell.xib for ParentCellIdentifier

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ChildCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:ParentCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSDate* date = [_dates objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.dateToDislpay = date; //here goes the error
```

When trying to set property of child cell, it crashes. It's correct, because in ParentCell.xib class of the cell is ParentCell.
After changing the class in xib, it works, but I want to stick with my parent class in xib, since I will use the same xib, but with different formatters only.

How can I do it?

**EDIT1:**
crash received:

```
-[ParentCell setDateToDislpay:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Comment: what is crash please post error

Comment: Added edit: it's unrecognized selector sent to instance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go into the xib file and change the class type to `ChildCell` and that should fix your crash.

To subclass see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5056886/848719

You'll have to override `initWithFrame:` and `awakeFromNib`.

Comment: That's what I did. I want, however, to stick with the ParentClass in xib since I am going to create multiple child classes with different formatters for labels using the the parent's xib.

Answer (score 0):

You got crash because you have register  `[UINib nibWithNibName:@"ParentCell" bundle:nil]` Parent Cell and in cell for item you are create object of `ChildCell` , but it is parent cell not child cell 
and parent cell does not have `dateToDislpay` property .

you can check same with print class

you are doing inheritance wrong way, you should read some tutorial or read some demos

Comment: I know that and I mentioned it in my question. The real question is how to use same xib for different classes of views.

Comment: there is no reason i can see here that why you are taking  parent cell, parent cell contains the IBOutlets which are weak